# matrix/quaternion woes

Tags: math, opengl, matrix, trigonometry, quaternions

So I got two matrices, the modelview matrix (should only rotates on the Y axis) and a rotation matrix (only rotates on the Y axis).

Now I need to know what the angle is of the projection (the view I'm looking at) and the rotation matrix's angle then I need to assign a vallue (between 0 and 8) based on that result.

or any other way I can add two rotations together and get a value between 0 and 8.

So basically if you're looking 90d and the enemy is walking 180d you'll see the sprite of the enemy drawn going right.

Comment: any chance you could draw what you mean?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28109593/example.png
Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget matrices for now, based on your picture I think all you need is:

```
direction = (model_view_rotation + enemy_rotation) % 360
direction = floor((direction + 22.5) / 45.0)
```

which should give you a value between 0 and 8

I'm assuming that view 8 is actually the same as view 0 ?

Comment: This worked for the angle, but upon seeing it I realize I need to account for the cameras xz position relative to the enemy too. any chance you could add that so I know I'm doing it right?

Comment: @CyanPrime I'll need another drawing (best seen from above), but I don't be able to look until tomorrow now.

Comment: Okay, did some more coding and found I didn't need the camera zx after all. Accepting the answer now. Thank you very much ^_^